# c++ error initialize an attribute of parent class

Tags: c++

I've a problem because a derived class can't initialize the attribute of a the parent class. In the code below the error is given in the main section. (I know that this code is stupid, but I semplified)

class.cpp

```
# include < iostream >
# include < stdexcept >
using namespace std;

template < typename T > class A;
template < typename T > class B;

template < typename T > class A{

protected:

T **m;
int r;

void allocate_mem(T ***ptr){
    *ptr = new T*[1];
    (*ptr)[0] = new T[1];
}

public:

A(){
    throw logic_error("Error!");
}

~A(){
    delete[] m[0];
    delete[] m;
}

};

template < typename T > class B: public A<T>{

public:

B(int val):
A<T>::r(0){                 //no type named 'r' in 'class A<int>'
    A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
    A<T>::m[0][0] = val;
 }

};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

B <int> a(4);  //here the error is called

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The initializer list should be used on the class' direct member variables.  If you want set/assign values to the parent's members, do inside the definition of the constructor.

Comment: You need a convert constructor for `B`